# Optimize code in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi have multiple handles defined in my components that update the state of the store based on the element changed

```
_handleHyperlink2ColorChange:function(color){
     this._setDataChanged('hyperlink1_color');
    var updateObj = {
                       bannerData:{
                           hyperlink2Color:color,
                       },
                     };
     this._handleFormChange(updateObj);
   },

   _handleDescriptionChange:function(newDescription){
     this._setDataChanged('banner_description');
     var updateObj = {
                       bannerData:{
                           description:newDescription,
                       },
                     };
      this._handleFormChange(updateObj);   
   },

   _handleHeadingChange:function(newHeading){
     this._setDataChanged('banner_heading');
     var updateObj = {
                       bannerData:{
                          heading:newHeading,
                       },
                     };

     this._handleFormChange(updateObj);
   },
```

As we can see all three handlers have nothing different in them other then the property that is to be changed .So how can I handle this in one function?

Basically I want to know how can I handle the property name using a variable ?

***EDIT***

Following the the example of how these handlers are being called

```
 this.props.onDescriptionChange(this.state.slideDetails);
```

Where `OnDescriptionChange` carries `_handleDescriptionChange` from parent to child component

Answer (score 0):

You could "build" those functions like this:

```
function builder(selector, property){
    return function(value){

     this._setDataChanged(selector);
         var updateObj = {
             bannerData:{}
         };
         updateObj.bannerData[property] = value;
         this._handleFormChange(updateObj);  
    };
};

_handleHyperlink2ColorChange: builder("hyperlink1_color", "hyperlink2Color"),
_handleDescriptionChange: builder("banner_description", "description"),
_handleHeadingChange: builder("banner_heading", "heading"),
```

Now all you have to do is pass the unique names from the functions to the `builder` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/bind).

```
_handlePropertyChange: function(dataChanged, propertyName, newValue){
     this._setDataChanged(dataChanged);
     var updateObj = { bannerData: {} };
     updateObj.bannerData[propertyName] = newValue;
     this._handleFormChange(updateObj);
}
```

Then, bind additional arguments to the callback you pass in your child component props.

```
<ChildComponent
    onDescriptionChange={this._handlePropertyChange('banner_description', 'description')}
/>
```